# How to find last update/insert/delete operation time on mongodb collection without objectid field

Tags: mongodb, collections

I have some unused collections in the MongoDb database. I've to find out when the CRUD operations done against collections in the database. We have our own _id field instead of mongo's default object_id. We dont have any time filed in the collections to find out the modification time. is there any way to find out the modification time of collections in mongodb from meta data? Is there any data dictionay informations like in oracle to find out this? please give some idea/workarounds

Comment: if there is no time field , how can you think about find modification time

Comment: @Alok: why we can't think? In other databases like oracle having Data Dictionary views even though you dont have time filed .

Comment: @alok:If I know all about mongodb operations there is no need to come up with questions in this forum right? If suppose this option available in mongodb then ,it is very handy for admin tasks. people are here having great knowledge . So I can get help from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a long story short: MongoDB has a *flexible* schema. Simply add a date field. Since older entries don't have it, they can not be the last entry.

Let's call that field `mtime`.

So after adding a date field to your schema definition, we generate an index in descending order on the new field:

```js
db.yourCollction.createIndex({mtime:-1})
```

Finding the last mtime for a collection now is easy:

```js
db.yourCollection.find({"mtime":{"$exists":true}}).sort({"mtime":-1}).limit(1)
```

Do this for every collection. When the above query does not return a value within the timeframe you defined for purging a collection, simply drop it, since it has not been modified since you introduced the mtime field.

After your collections are cleaned up, you may remove the `mtime` field from your schema definition. To remove it from the documents, you can run a simple query:

```js
db.yourCollection.update(
  { "mtime":{ $exists:true} },
  { "$unset":{ "mtime":""} },
  { multi: true}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no "data dictionary" to get this information in MongoDB.

**If** you've enabled the profiling level in advance to log all operations (`db.setProfilingLevel(2)`) and you haven't had many operations to log, so that the [`system.profile` capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) hasn't overwritten whatever logs you are interested in, you can get the information you need there—but otherwise it's gone.