# time of last insertion/updation/deletion in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, timestamp

I need to find out the timestamp of last operation (insertion/updation/deletion) done in mongoDB.

I'm querying `oplog.rs` for this but I'm unable to find the timestamp of the last operation as the `_id` of the documents are custom and oplog document doesn't have it's own `_id` field.

Is there any elegant way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for the "last operation", or are you looking for the "last modification of a document". For the latter you should create a "lastModified" field and give that the current date in all operations. The oplog just stores "operations", and not the `_id` values of documents that where modified.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383612/how-to-find-last-update-insert-delete-operation-time-on-mongodb-collection-witho