# Get last modified date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can I know the date when was my collection (or collections) in MongoDB were modified using mongoose? I did research and I did not find any resources that would answer my question so looking for help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find last update/insert/delete operation time on mongodb collection without objectid field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383612/how-to-find-last-update-insert-delete-operation-time-on-mongodb-collection-witho)

Answer (score 0):

if you add `timestamps` to your collection config, it'll track the date of your change with a property called `updatedAt`. refer to the [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps)

Comment: I cannot because I am not defining the collection myself I am receiving data from my client and then basically just storing it to my database

Comment: you mean you are querying the database directly without using mongoose? if so, you should add such a property yourself and give it `Date.now()` every time you want to query the database @Heb99

Comment: So let me explain - I have a json Array, which my client is reading from the file and then sending it to API. Then the API would store those to the database using mongoose. Now in order to stop the duplication of data that is been stored in the database, I just want to store the data that has been updated to the database rather than storing the whole data for teh second time.